# What is the state of the film "Mobius" by Lynne Ramsay, a science fiction take on Moby Dick?

Tags: mobius

Round about 2012 I was seeing lots of articles on the internet about how the film director Lynne Ramsay was preparing a SF film based on Herman Melville's novel *Moby Dick*. As no film has surfaced (sorry, no pun intended) in the last ten years I think it is safe to assume that this project is lost in development hell or, officially dead in the water... (I'm sorry I'll stop).

Based on the interviews Ramsay gave the project seem to have been reasonably well developed, she goes as far as saying in an interview with the Guardian Newspaper in 2012 that the film's tile will be "Mobius" and that the script is written by Ramsay and Rory Kinnear. Her IMDb page still has a project titled "Mobius" listed, but as I don't have access to IMDb pro I can find no further information on this.

Does anyone know if it is the same film? Is there a script? Is this an active project or not... Links to recent interviews/press releases/ comments by Ramsey or Kinnear or even whale sightings are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't that a Futurama episode?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The most up to date information I can find on the project is this interview with Lynne Ramsay from 20<sup>th</sup> January 2018. It would appear as though the project is not currently being worked on.

> **I’ve read about your next intended project, Mobius, reported to be a sci-fi version of Moby Dick. Can you say a little bit about it and whether it’s still on?**
>
> It’s one of those projects which has been fermenting for a while. It’s funny saying Moby Dick is a sci-fi in space, because it’s not that. In fact, it has some of the things that I am interested in, like impotence and revenge and chasing ghosts for no reason. These are the things that made me look at the bigger things in the book. But I’ve still got these ideas going round in my head. I’d love to do a soundtrack based on the things that I’m thinking about before I make the movie. Right now, I want to write because I’ve just done a film and when it’s born into the world, I probably don’t watch it again for 20 years!
>
> <sub>[filmint., Out of a Bleak Past: An Interview with Lynne Ramsay on *You Were Never Really Here*](http://filmint.nu/interview-ramsay-really/)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

There's an interview on Film International, who say that they have been covering film since 1973, and this interview was in 2018, just a couple of years ago.

She says it's an SF treatment of Moby Dick, set in space - but:

> It's funny saying its *Moby Dick* is a sci-fi set in space, because it's not that. In fact, it's got the things I'm interested in, like impotence and revenge and chasing ghosts for no reason.

But nothing about any kind of 'developmental hell'.

There's not much else that is recent, unsurprisingly, if it's a work in progress.

Comment: Looks like I beat you to the answer here as I posted one 10 minutes earlier with the full quote about Mobius. You missed out the most relevant parts of her quote though where she states _"It’s one of those projects which has been fermenting for a while."_

Comment: You should also include the link to the interview in the answer itself to source where the quote comes from.